# How do I set/get cookies in a controller (custom module)?

Tags: 9, page-controller

I have a module and I need to set a simple cookie (if not exists). And after each request I need to read the value of the cookie and maybe update.

I have read many articles and tried many ways but no success. The only one, which works, returns a "response" object. But my controller should still work, even after response->header sent/saved.

This is the controller code.

```php
namespace Drupal\my_custom_mod1\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class myController extends ControllerBase {

    public function main() {
      $cookie = new Cookie(
        "my_cookie_name",                      
        'some value for the cookie',                                       
        (new \DateTime('now'))->modify("+111 day"), 
        "/",                                     
      );
      $res = new Response();
      $res->headers->setCookie($cookie);
      return $res; // if this line deactivated, no cookie will be set

      return [
        '#type' =>      'inline_template',
        '#context' => [
          'my_html_output' => " my text / html output "
        ]
      ];
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to set a cookie on a rendered page you have to use an event subscriber and set it on the rendered HTML response. BTW Drupal doesn't work well with cookies, better use session values.

Comment: Do you need the cookie to be read by external applications? That's pretty much the only use I can think of for working with cookies in Drupal 8+. Maybe there's a Drupal API that would serve you better.

Comment: You can't do it this way. The controller has to return a Response in this instance, and not a render array. You can't do both. The headers have to make it back to the client. That said, unless you have a very specific reason for using cookies, its best to avoid them. Managed hosting platforms like Acquia, Pantheon etc typically have a proxy server that strips out cookies going in/out unless you use a specific naming convention. Also note that cookies will interfere and or stop things from being cached, so expect a performance hit.

Comment: Thank you!  
  
I think Drupal sessions expire faster than cookies. That's why I need to work with cookies.  
  
It is about a "Favorites Module" for an educational institution. Anonymous users should be able to mark courses on the MyFavoritesList (MVL) so they can find them later. They should also be able to add all the other pages like contact, news, etc.  
  
   
And they should still be able to see this list a few months later. Of course, if the browser cache has not been emptied.

Comment: It seems like durable information like that should be stored with the user account, server-side.

Comment: Cookies expire. This should be tracked in user accounts.

Comment: You want private temp store.